How can I fit and predict each model from workflow_map results?
I am using tidymodels to train various classification models and to tune hyperparameters within these models using parsnip. As a newcomer to tidymodels, I have completed some tasks by following tutorials. However, I am unsure how to fit and predict each model using the tuned hyperparameters from workflow_map, rather than just extracting the best workflow and fitting that one. I am interested in understanding the fitted and prediction results for each model and identifying any unpredicted cases. I am currently unable to figure out how to fit and predict a series of workflows with a set of hyperparameters using a composite function like workflow_map. My current approach is to manually substitute each one, which might be somewhat inefficient. Here is some of my code(actually, I used 16 models, here I pasted 2 of them):
set.seed(123)
splits <- initial_split(Mydata, strata = Y,prop = 0.70)
TrainData <- training(splits)
TestData <- testing(splits)


base_rec <- recipe( Y ~ ., data = TrainData)
dummy_rec<-recipe( Y ~ ., data = TrainData)%>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

library(ranger)
rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest(
    mtry = tune(),
    min_n = tune(),
    trees = tune()
    ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")%>% 
  translate()

bt_spec <- 
  bart(
    trees = tune(),
    prior_terminal_node_coef = tune(),
    prior_terminal_node_expo = tune(),
    prior_outcome_range = tune()
    ) %>% 
  set_engine("dbarts")%>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  translate()

all_workflows <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(base_recipe = base_rec),
    models = list(
      rf=rf_spec, bart=bt_spec)
  )%>%
  option_add(control = control_grid(
               extract = function(x) x,
               parallel_over = "resamples",
               save_pred = TRUE,
               save_workflow = TRUE))

#create resampling objects for later tuning
set.seed(123)
folds <- vfold_cv(TrainData, v = 5)

wf_tuning <- 
  all_workflows %>% 
  workflow_map("tune_grid", 
               seed=12345, 
               resamples = folds, 
               grid = 25, 
               metrics = metric_set(accuracy), 
               verbose = TRUE)
autoplot(wf_tuning)

If I manually extract the tuned hyperparameters and then fit and predict the model, I should do the same procedure for 25*16 times. Could you please provide some suggestions for a more efficient approach?

You can add an option to save the workflow in the results then use fit_best() to get the trained models on the best parameter combination:
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(1)
sim_data <- sim_regression(250)
sim_rs <- vfold_cv(sim_data)

cart_spec <- 
  decision_tree(cost_complexity = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

mars_spec <- 
  mars(prod_degree =tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

wflows <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(basic = outcome ~ .),
    models = list(cart = cart_spec, mars = mars_spec),
    cross = TRUE)

wflow_res <- 
  wflows %>% 
  workflow_map(
    seed = 2,
    resamples = sim_rs,
    grid = 10,
    control = control_grid(save_workflow = TRUE)
  )

with_best_fits <- 
  wflow_res %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(result, ~ fit_best(.x, metric = "rmse")))

with_best_fits$fit
#> [[1]]
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: decision_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> outcome ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> n= 250 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#>   1) root 250 138175.0000  15.7340300  
#>     2) predictor_04< 5.005281 233 108125.5000  13.2361200  
#>       4) predictor_04>=-5.67335 221  81891.5800  10.9861600  
#>         8) predictor_18>=-0.04129457 118  40858.3500   4.2061130  
#>          16) predictor_14< 3.064134 95  26406.7600   0.6664635  
#>            32) predictor_14< -2.539472 22   7014.9180 -10.0433000  
#>              64) predictor_18>=2.279312 9   2418.6340 -24.2686700 *
#>              65) predictor_18< 2.279312 13   1514.1670  -0.1949626 *
#>            33) predictor_14>=-2.539472 73  16108.0000   3.8940630  
#>              66) predictor_09< -0.7610177 42  10034.8300  -0.5414930  
#>               132) predictor_04< 0.9336627 30   6400.4920  -4.7811980  
#>                 264) predictor_14< -1.061535 9   4314.9580 -13.9170600 *
#>                 265) predictor_14>=-1.061535 21   1012.4270  -0.8658293  
#>                   530) predictor_16< 0.2395412 14    393.8731  -4.3145150 *
#>                   531) predictor_16>=0.2395412 7    119.0292   6.0315430 *
#>               133) predictor_04>=0.9336627 12   1746.9510  10.0577700 *
#>              67) predictor_09>=-0.7610177 31   4127.3320   9.9035250  
#>               134) predictor_04>=-2.137203 22   2225.2690   6.3287210  
#>                 268) predictor_10>=-1.785821 15   1172.6710   2.6434810 *
#>                 269) predictor_10< -1.785821 7    412.3508  14.2256600 *
#>               135) predictor_04< -2.137203 9    933.6820  18.6419400 *
#>          17) predictor_14>=3.064134 23   8345.0050  18.8264000  
#>            34) predictor_06< 2.689544 16   2544.6270  13.0448800 *
#>            35) predictor_06>=2.689544 7   4043.1270  32.0413100 *
#>         9) predictor_18< -0.04129457 103  29394.5700  18.7536000  
#>          18) predictor_14< 2.859504 83  21343.1800  15.7495900  
#>            36) predictor_18>=-2.907324 56  10884.7500  10.5042200  
#>              72) predictor_07< -3.013126 12   3536.4490   0.6905080 *
#>              73) predictor_07>=-3.013126 44   5877.4010  13.1806900  
#>               146) predictor_20>=0.7343885 15   1681.9700   7.2229070 *
#>               147) predictor_20< 0.7343885 29   3387.6110  16.2623000  
#>                 294) predictor_14< -0.6088161 10   1057.5280   8.9745340 *
#>                 295) predictor_14>=-0.6088161 19   1519.4330  20.0979600 *
#>            37) predictor_18< -2.907324 27   5721.9630  26.6288700  
#>              74) predictor_12>=-1.279433 19   3490.4090  21.8447500 *
#>              75) predictor_12< -1.279433 8    763.8750  37.9911500 *
#>          19) predictor_14>=2.859504 20   4194.0540  31.2202300  
#>            38) predictor_16>=-0.5423066 10    322.7158  21.1905000 *
#>            39) predictor_16< -0.5423066 10   1859.4290  41.2499600 *
#>       5) predictor_04< -5.67335 12   4511.2250  54.6727800 *
#>     3) predictor_04>=5.005281 17   8669.7690  49.9701500 *
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: mars()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> outcome ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Selected 24 of 39 terms, and 11 of 20 predictors
#> Termination condition: Reached nk 41
#> Importance: predictor_04, predictor_18, predictor_19, predictor_20, ...
#> Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 11 12
#> GCV 91.03479    RSS 13353.8    GRSq 0.8366059    RSq 0.9033559


Thanks for your response topepo. I know fit_best() function and that is used to fit the optimal result. I love that way. BUT what stuck me was how to take the tuned hyperparameters of each workflow and fit each workflow and then make predictions. Maybe that is not a common way. I want to check the unpredicted cases of each workflow.
